# Restore the value of vertical bars to its initial position using D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm currently using a D3 code in which the vertical bars increases their width corresponding to the slider movement. But when we reach back to the default position I want the bars to show the initial value instead of default. To make the slider work I'm using the Math.min function of jquery, but this is not working perfectly. CA anyone please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <style>

    .axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}

body {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    <!--padding-top:50px;-->
}

div#slider{
    width: 940px;
    margin-left: 8%;

    margin-top: 4%; 
    }
svg {
    margin-left:3%; 
    }
    </style>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="jqueryui@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
    <script data-require="jqueryui@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script data-require="d3@*" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>

  </head>

 <body>
    <div id="slider"></div>
    <script>
    $(function() {

        $("#slider").slider({
            min: 30,
            max: 950,
            // on slide adjust width of all rects
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                svg.selectAll("rect")
                        .attr("width", function (d) {
                            return Math.min(ui.value * d.rate, d.max);
                        })
            }
        });

        // create svg
        var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", 950)
                .attr("height", 400);


        // add 4 rects
        var data = [
            { row:1, rate:0.4, max:550 },
            { row:2, rate:0.5, max:600 },
            { row:3, rate:0.6, max:700 },
            { row:4, rate:0.7, max:750 },
            { row:5, rate:0.8, max:780 },
            { row:6, rate:0.9, max:800 },
            { row:7, rate:1.0, max:950 },
        ];

        svg.selectAll("g")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", 20)
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return d.row * 30;
                })
                .attr("height", 20)
                .attr("width", 20)
                .style("fill","blue")
                .style("margin-top",20)
                .attr("transform", "translate(20,0)");

      //add x and y axis
   var x = d3.scale.linear()
                    .range([0, 950]);

                var y = d3.scale.linear()
                    .range([200, 0]);

                       var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(x)
                    .orient("bottom")
                    .ticks(5)


                var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(y)
                    .orient("left")
                    .ticks(7);

                     x.domain([0,25]);

                y.domain([0,7]);

                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "x axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(30,260)")
                    .call(xAxis);

                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "y axis")
                     .attr("transform", "translate(20,30)")
                    .call(yAxis);

    });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your slide event:

```
slide: function(event, ui) {
    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .attr("width", function (d) {
            return Math.min(ui.value * d.rate, d.max);
    })
}
```

You would want to put a condition utilizing `ui.value`

Something like this:

```
slide: function(event, ui) {
    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .attr("width", function (d) {
            if(ui.value === 0){
                // return your default width here
            } else {
                return Math.min(ui.value * d.rate, d.max);
            }
    })
}
```

Comment: Unable to implement this, I've tried using a variable to store the initial value. Can you please help.

Comment: Well I'm not sure exactly what you're plotting but shouldn't something like this work: `return data[0].rate` or `data[0].max`?

Comment: Here is the code I'm using please check:
svg.selectAll("rect")
                        .attr("width", function (d) {
       if(ui.value === 0){
        return inival;
     } else{
                            return Math.min(ui.value * d.rate, d.min);}
                        })
            }
        });

Comment: var data = [
            { row:1, rate:1.0, min:200, max:350 },
            { row:2, rate:1.0, min:250, max:400 },
            { row:3, rate:1.0, min:280, max:475 },
            { row:4, rate:1.0, min:320, max:510 },
            { row:5, rate:1.0, min:350, max:530 },
            { row:6, rate:1.0, min:375, max:550 },
            { row:7, rate:1.0, min:400, max:600 },
        ];
var inival = [data[0].min, data[1].min, data[2].min, data[3].min, data[4].min, data[5].min, data[6].min];

Comment: Since your data is hard-coded, you should simply be able to reference the initial value. Also, my example is assuming that `ui.value === 0` is the default point on the slider. I'm not sure I can help you further on this as it really is quite straightforward - as far as I can tell.